# What is the maximum memory that can be defined in Rider?

Tags: memory-management, out-of-memory, heap-memory, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am working with JetBrains Rider IDE on Windows 10 and I get the bellow error in the image.

Current default shows as 1500. What can be the maximum ?

[image: memory error]